# String array pointer in C passing only one char

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have an input file that is just

Apple
Banana
Pear
etc. all on different lines

and I need to use a loop to go line-by-line assigning each string to a variable, and then later passing that string to other functions. I am doing this by using fscanf (required). Currently I have in my main()

```
char *name;
for (i=0; i<=fileLength; i++) {
    input(fp1, name)
    printf("%s", &name);
    // later would pass name elsewhere
}
```

and

```
void input(FILE *fp1, char name) {
    fscanf(fp1, "%s", &name);
    printf("%s", &name);
}
```

If I run the printf statement from the input function, I get the whole string perfectly. If I run it from main, I just get "A". It does not later change to "B" when doing the banana line, although the printf statement in the input function prints out correctly. What gives and how can I get the name var printed out in my main(), and later be able to pass that var?

Comment: `char name`...hmmmm

Comment: `void input(FILE *fp1, char *name) {
    fscanf(fp1, "%s", name);
    printf("%s", name);
}` for starters

Comment: `char *name` is initialized, you need to allocate space for it.

Comment: I only think the are 3481 answers to nearly the exact same question on the site. (I think you could probably search `Apple Banana Pear` and find at least a dozen) `:)`

Comment: You need to study pointers and arrays before you can write this program. The code posted has too many fundamental misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behavior.

You can't store a string of more than 0 characters in a single `char` (since the terminator takes one char, you can have 0 characters of actual string before it in that case).

You must use character arrays to make some space:

```
void input(char *name, FILE *fp1)
{
  if(fscanf(fp1, "%s", name) == 1)
    printf("%s\n", name);
}
```

Then call it like this, for instance:

```
char namebuffer[128];

input(namebuffer, fp1);
```

Note that I've edited this to use `fscanf()` since that was a requirement, but this is a really bad solution. It won't read a string with whitespace in it, so a typical "firstname lastname" full name won't read correctly. There are ways around that, but I'm not sure where to draw the line here.

Also buffer overflow can easily happen here since there's no protection. This can be added while keeping `fscanf()` but it's a bit annoying.

Comment: May also want to use `char *input...` and be able to return success/failure (`NULL`) to the caller. (OP also noted using `fscanf` as a requirement -- poor guy)

Answer (score 0):

You are using an initialized pointer `char *name`, which leads to undefined behavior. You need to make sure `name` has enough space hold the strings you are reading from the file. You can simply create a VLA, such as `char name[n]`, which can hold up to `n` characters. Another option would be dynamically allocate `name`, but this can create unnecessary overhead.

You also need to check return of `fscanf()`, as it returns the number of items scanned. In your case, you would want to read one word at a time, until EOF. It would be better to also use [`fgets(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read input, instead of `fscanf()`.

Here is a small example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORDSIZE 100

/* function which reads one word */
int input(FILE *stream, char word[]) {
    if (fscanf(stream, " %99s", word) != 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *fptr;

    /* array which holds words */
    char word[WORDSIZE];

    fptr = fopen("somewords.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Keeps running loop until input() returns 0 */
    while (input(fptr, word)) {
        printf("%s\n", word);
    }

    return 0;
}
```